# What is the meaning of the expression "an arrow in Satan's eye?"

Tags: talmud-gemara

The expression "an arrow in Satan's eye" is from the Talmud. What is the meaning of the expression "an arrow in Satan's eye?"

Answer (score 2):

It's an expression that Peleimu used to say about the evil inclination as we see in [Kiddushin 81a](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.81a.15?with=all&lang=bi)

> פלימו הוה רגיל למימר כל יומא **גירא בעיניה דשטן**‏

In [Steinsaltz](https://www.sefaria.org/Steinsaltz_on_Kiddushin.81a.15?with=all&lang=bi) Gemara it's explained as follows:

> החכם פלימו הוה [היה] רגיל למימר** [לומר] כל יומא [יום]: גירא בעיניה [חץ בעיניו] של השטן, שהיה צוחק מפיתויי היצר.‏
>
> The Sage Peleimu had the habit to say every day: **An arrow in the eye of Satan**, mocking the temptations of the evil inclination.

The same expression is mentioned in [Menachot 62a](https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.62a.17?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&with=all&lang=bi) with a similar explanation:

> רב אחא בר יעקב ממטי ליה ומייתי ליה ומחוי הכי ואמר **גירא בעינא דשטנא**
>
> The Gemara relates: Rav Aḥa bar Ya’akov would extend and bring back the lulav in this manner, and would say: I am hereby **shooting an arrow in the eye of Satan,** as despite Satan’s best efforts, the Jewish people continue to fulfill mitzvot joyously

Answer (score 2):

The meaning may vary slightly by context. In Kiddushin [29b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=29b&format=pdf)-[30a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=30&format=pdf) we find the following:

> אמר רב חסדא האי דעדיפנא מחבראי דנסיבנא בשיתסר ואי הוה נסיבנא בארביסר
>   הוה הוה אמינא לשטן גירא בעיניך
>
> R. Hisda said: The reason that I am superior to my colleagues is that
>   I married at sixteen. And had I married at fourteen, I would have said
>   to Satan, An arrow in your eye. ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/nashim/Kiddushin.pdf))

[Rashi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi) there explains as follows:

> כלומר הייתי מתגרה בו ושטן הוא יצר הרע ולא אירא שיחטיאני
>
> That is to say, I would have provoked him – and Satan is the
>   Evil Inclination – and it would not occur that he would cause me to
>   sin.

Tosafot Ri Hazaken there ([misatributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_ben_Samuel#Tosafot)) writes:

> חץ ומשל הוא
>
> An arrow, and it is a metaphor.

[R. Samuel Eidels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maharsha) writes:

> וענין גירא בעין ע"ש שהעין תחלת סרסור דעבירה
>
> [As for] the matter of "arrow in the eye", see there that the eye is the
>   beginning of the agent of sin.

[R. Yechiel Michel Epstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yechiel_Michel_Epstein) ([Aruch Hashulchan E.H. 1:11](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14243&st=&pgnum=5)) adds:

> כלומר שהיצר לא היה מתגבר עליו כל ימי חייו
>
> That is to say that the Inclination would have never overpowered him all
>   the days of his life.

[Jastrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcus_Jastrow), in his [dictionary](http://www.tyndalearchive.com/tabs/jastrow/), translates the phrase as:

> I should say to Satan I defy thee;